# Image upload issue Laravel 4 - File is being corrupted

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to `upload` an `image` using `laravel4` and I've successfully managed to upload a `file` from a `form` and store it in a directory of my choice in the public folder. However the issue I am running into is viewing the images. I am developing in `Netbeans` and when I try to open my newly uploaded image I am told the image is corrupted.

This is my form:

```
<form action="{{ action('BookController@handleCreate') }}" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" />          
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Description</label>
            <input type="textarea" class="form-control" name="desc" />          
        </div>
        <!-- Img upload -->
        <input type="file" name="img"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <a href="{{ action('BookController@index') }}" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</a>
    </form>
```

This is my `controller`:

```
public function handleCreate(){
        $book = new Book;

        $book->book_name = Input::get('name');
        $book->book_desc = Input::get('desc');

        $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/covers/';//Set up destination path
        $file = Input::file('img');//Get the file
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();//Get the extension
        $filename = str_random(12).".".$extension;//Create a filename
        $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);//Move the file to the destination

        $pathToFile = '/uploads/covers/'.$filename;
        echo $pathToFile;

        //If successful.....
        if($upload_success){
            $book->book_cover = $filename;//store value in db
            $book->save();//Save the book
            return Redirect::action('BookController@index');
        }else{//Else return to form with an error message....
            return Response::json('error', 400);
        }
    }
```

This is the `path` to my image

```
/uploads/covers/VFBDJPqEdI6P.jpg
```

My plan is that I will store this path in the `database` and use it to display the image on the screen.

I don't know why but whilst I am uploading the files they are being corrupted and I'd appreciate if someone might suggest a way I could fix this.

Regards

Comment: Is your OS prompting the message or NetBeans?

Comment: netbeans but if I navigate to directory on local host and try to open the image it is not being opened either

Comment: there is nothing in your code that is directly manipulating the image in any way, either there's something else you haven't show us or the image your trying to upload is corrupt in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked without losing any content

```
 Storage::put($pathToFile,file_get_contents($request->file('img')->getRealPath()));
```